# In istio AuthorizationPolicy How to match paths including query string parameters

Tags: security, istio

I'm currently using istio 1.4 and had enabled a `Policy` to check jwt.
I enabled an `AuthorizationPolicy` which have that rule:

```yaml
  rules
  - to:
    - operation:
        methods: ["GET"]
        paths: [
          "/render/checkout"
        ]
    when:
    - key: request.auth.claims[roles]
      values: ["USER"]
```

When I hit that path with my jwt, every thing works great. The problem is when I hit the same url with a query string parameter for example `/render/checkout?sort=asc`, I get a `RBAC: access denied`.
to bypass this, I ended up adding the path including the question mark and a wildcard:

```yaml
paths: [
          "/render/checkout", "/render/checkout?*"
        ]
```

but having a lot of paths and a lot of microservices, I feel that should not happen as it happens because it's very repetitive and error prone.

I know that there's already an [issue on github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16585) about supporting regex in paths, but currently :

Can I avoid doubling each of my paths, one without query string parameters and the second with the query string parameters?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22111) where someone asked same question few days ago which leads us to github issue you [add](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16585).

Specially this part of [github member answer](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16585#issuecomment-597973216) @GODBS.

---

> There is no other way to exclude paths for JWT then to use an Authorization Policy which does not allow regex.

---

> Can I avoid doubling each of my paths, one without query string parameters and the second with the query string parameters?

So as far as I understand currently there is no other way to make it work. The workaround for now is to add another paths, like you did.

I assume they will add it in the future, the question here is how long will it take.